# Closure and interior of sets in this topology?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

i have a topology $\theta$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined with it's basis $\mathcal{B}$ is the  family of all sets $$D_{a,b,c}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2, y>ax+b; y>-ax+c\}$$ where $a>0$ and $b,c\in \mathbb{R}$

I want to find the closur and the interior of the following sets 
\begin{align}
& A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2, y^2+x^2<1\},\\
& B=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2, x>0\},\\
& C=\{(0,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2, y>0\}.
\end{align}

It is clear for me that $\overset{\circ}{A}=\emptyset=\overset{\circ}{B}$ and $\overset{\circ}{C}=C$

But i have a problem with the closure of each set?

Thank you

Comment: Is $C$ $\{(0,y)\dots\}$ or $\{(x,y)\dots\}$?

Comment: no as it is writen $C=\{(0,y), y>0\}$

Comment: So just the positive $y$-axis? I think $\overset\circ C=\emptyset$ as well then.

Comment: i think that C is open because if i replace x=0 b=c=0, in $D_{a,b,c}=C$ @AkivaWeinberger

Comment: $D_{a,0,0}=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2,y>ax,y>-ax\}$ always contains things not on the $y$-axis (for example, $(1,2a)$).

Comment: ohh $C$ is jut an element from $D_{a,0,0}$ so ok $\overset{\circ}{C}=\emptyset$

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the closure of $A$ will look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7e9hR.png) and that the closures of $B$ and $C$ will be the entire plane.

Comment: i consider the family of closed set $F_{a,b,c}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2, y\leq ax+b ~\text{or} y\leq -a x+c\}$ so when i draw a picture i think that the closure is what is under the line tangent to the circle , $F_{a,1,1}$ no ?

Comment: What's the definition of closure?

Comment: smallest closed set which contains $A$ @Akiva

Comment: And a set is closed if its complement is open, and a set is open if for every point in it there's a basis set containing it contained in the set.

Comment: F is the complement of D

Comment: Yes, and?${}{}$

Comment: i think that  that the smallest closed set which contains A is F for a>0, b=c=1

Comment: But the set in the picture I posted is closed and smaller, no?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/XM7qkee.png

Comment: i don't understand why it is closed it is the complement of any D ?

Comment: Not every open set is a basis set. Not every closed set is the complement of a basis set. Do you remember the definition of a basis, or of a topology generated by a basis?

Comment: yes i agree with you but i must give it a name not juste draw it

Comment: $\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\le1\}\cup\\\{(x,y):-1\le x\le1\text{ and }y\le0\}$.

Comment: can i say that it is  $\cap  D^c_{a,1,1}$

Comment: No, that just gives the set of points in and below the line $y=1$, doesn't it?

Comment: and how to prove that the set is closed ?

Comment: Show that its complement is open, meaning that for every point in the complement, there is a basis set containing the point contained in the complement

Comment: it's complement is $$\{(x,y), x^2+y^2>1\}\cap \{(x,y); |x|>1~\text{or}~ y>0\}$$ i don't see what D which is include in this

Comment: Draw pictures${}$

Comment: the complement is $\{(x,y), x^2+y^2>1\}\cap \{(x,y); |x|>1~\text{or}~ y>0\}$ or $\{(x,y), x^2+y^2>1\}\cap \{(x,y); |x|>1~\text{and}~ y>0\}$ pleease?

Comment: The one with or

Comment: so i think that it is $]1,+\infty[\times]1,+\infty[\cup ]-\infty,-1[\times]1,+\infty[$

Comment: I don't see how that makes sense. Please, draw pictures, you're not gonna figure this out algebraically.

Comment: i do it from a picture i don't see how i can find an other thing

Comment: i have a problem with the circle but i don't know an other way please help me